# Not able to access tables from a corrupted MySQL Dump file

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, sed, grep

```
grep -n "Table Structure" dumpfile.sql
```

returns

```
XXXXXX:-- Table structure for table `table_name_1`
XXXXXX:-- Table structure for table `table_name_2`
XXXXXX:-- Table structure for table `table_name_3`
```

But after this point, it breaks. Not sure why ?

AND also 
For retrieving a single table from huge dump file (Around 489GB), I used:

```
sed -n -e '/Table Structure 'table_name'/p' dump_file_name.sql > extracted_file.sql
```

But it is not able to locate the `table_name`.

So my question here is. How can all the tables be accessed ? Or why is it after certain table, it is not able to find the table.

Please If anyone can help me with this. It will be a greatest deed !

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"? If the dump file is corrupted, maybe those lines don't exist.

Comment: The data inside the file is too huge. the command stops executing further.

Comment: It sounds like this question would be more appropriate on [unix.se], since you're just asking about the behavior of the `grep` and `sed` commands with large files, not about how to write the `sed` expression. You should specify what OS you're on.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with your `sed` command.

First, you're using single quotes inside the string that's delimited by single quotes. That won't work, because the inside quotes will just end the shell string, not be included literally.

Second, the quotes in the dump file are backticks, not single quotes.

Also, you're missing `for table` in your pattern, and the `s` in `structure` should be lowercase.

```
sed -n -e '/Table structure for table `table_name`/p' dump_file_name.sql > extracted_file.sql
```

But you can just use `grep` for this, you don't need `sed`:

```
grep 'Table structure for table `table_name`' dump_file_name.sql > extracted_file.sql
```

Comment: In this case, It still finds all the table which has table structure in them and not what is required.